# Eclipse IDE - Python

Tags: eclipse, ide

Is there a way to change the color of the comments in python code edito? I would like to make them more bright so that I can see them. At the moment they are greyish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using PyDev for Eclipse. If not, you should probably install it, as it comes in quite handy.

Goto Preferences->PyDev->Editor. There you can adjust the colors.

Edit: This is what it looks like with PyDev: 6.5.0.

[image: PyDev Editor Color Options]

Comment: Found it - Thanks